Initialising a local variable in SwiftUI
I am building a MenuBar Extra which relates to the current application. I get the bundle id from the current application and use it to fetch or create new data. I am trying to pass data from one View to another for editing.
I want to keep a copy of the original value in the editing view for comparison.
I have created a local @State variable to store the data, and assigned it in the .onAppear part.
The problem is when the though the editing view correctly shows the data for the current value of the bundle id, the copy shows the data for the previous value.
Added for clarity:
For example, when I open the MenuBar app with XCode as the focus, I get:

If I switch to Firefox and open the app, I get:

Note that the “Original” is the value for the previous time. If I open on Firefox again, I get:

… so not it’s up to date.
I can’t think of any other way of initialising the variable that works.
How can I initialise the local variable correctly?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct XBApp: App {
    @State var bundleID: String = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Something", systemImage: "questionmark.bubble") {
            VStack {
                SampleContent(bundleID: $bundleID)
                    .modelContainer(for: SampleData.self)
                    .padding(0)
            }
            .onAppear {
                bundleID = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
                dbug(bundleID)
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

@Model
class SampleData {
    @Attribute(.unique) var bundle: String
    var data: String
    init(bundle: String, data: String) {
        self.bundle = bundle
        self.data = data
    }
}

struct EditSampleData: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var sampleData: SampleData
    @State var original: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(sampleData.bundle)
            Text(original)          //  out of step - shows previous version
            TextField("Data", text: $sampleData.data)
        }
        .onAppear {
            original = sampleData.data
        }
    }
}

struct SampleContent: View {
    @Binding var bundleID: String
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State var sampleData: SampleData?

    func loadData(bundleID: String) -> SampleData? {
        let filter = FetchDescriptor<SampleData>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.bundle == bundleID })
        do {
            if let sd = try modelContext.fetch(filter).first {
                return sd
            } else {
                let sd = SampleData(bundle: bundleID, data: "New Data: \(bundleID)")
                modelContext.insert(sd)
                return sd
            }
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let sd = sampleData {
                Text(sd.bundle)
                EditSampleData(sampleData: sd)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            sampleData = loadData(bundleID: bundleID)!
        }
    }
}


You say "I want to keep a copy of the original value in the editing view for comparison", but you also don't want the copy to go out of sync? The whole purpose of the copy is to have it not change so it's easy to compare with the new value, right?

Initialise it in the action that shows the editor and pass it in to editor as a binding

@Sweeper I want to copy set when the window opens, and not to change while editing. However, the original isn’t set with the new value on opening.

Please show a [mre]. You seem to have more going on with getting the bundle ID. How are you using SampleContent?

@Sweeper Done. The sample code is the full working code.

I think onAppear in a MenuBarExtra is only called once. It is not called when you re-open the menu bar window.

Perhaps one of the answers here would work.

Not really clear what you want to achieve with this setup,
but to make Text(original) display the changes that you make to sampleData.data,
try this approach:
 Text(original)  // <-- no longer out of step 
 TextField("Data", text: $sampleData.data)
     .onChange(of: sampleData.data) {
         original = sampleData.data
     }
 

EDIT-1
Try this approach declaring the original one step up from the EditSampleData, such as:
struct EditSampleData: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var sampleData: SampleData
    
    let original: String  // <--- here
    
    init(sampleData: SampleData, original: String) { // <--- here
        self.sampleData = sampleData
        self.original = original
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(sampleData.bundle)
            Text(original)
            TextField("Data", text: $sampleData.data)
        }
    }
}

struct SampleContent: View {
    @Binding var bundleID: String
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State var sampleData: SampleData?
    @State var original: String = "" // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let sd = sampleData {
                Text(sd.bundle)
                EditSampleData(sampleData: sd, original: original) // <--- here
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let xdata = loadData(bundleID: bundleID) {  // <--- here
                sampleData = xdata
                original = xdata.data
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadData(bundleID: String) -> SampleData? {
        let filter = FetchDescriptor<SampleData>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.bundle == bundleID })
        do {
            if let sd = try modelContext.fetch(filter).first {
                return sd
            } else {
                let sd = SampleData(bundle: bundleID, data: "New Data: \(bundleID)")
                modelContext.insert(sd)
                return sd
            }
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

}


Actually, I don’t want the original to change after the window is opened, but I do want it to have the correct value when the it is opened. Sorry for the poor wording; I’ve edited my question.

updated my answer addressing your revised question

I though I had tried something like that, but obviously not correctly. You solution did the job. Thanks again.
